# FIREBASE WARNING: Firebase.DataSnapshot.name() being deprecated

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire

```
firebase.js:39 FIREBASE WARNING: Firebase.DataSnapshot.name() being deprecated. Please use Firebase.DataSnapshot.key() instead.
```

multiple warnings in the console referring to the documentation

https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/api/datasnapshot/name.html

I'm not using Datasnapshot

```
var ref2 = new Firebase(CM_URL);
var reffyArray = $firebase(ref2).$asArray();
reffyArray.$loaded().then(function (data) {
    $scope.data.products = reffyArray;
}); // collections Object Loadedaphot
```

Comment: You appear to be using AngularFire. No doubt, it makes use of `DataSnapshot` in its implementation. What version of AngularFire are you using?

Comment: <script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/libs/angularfire/1.1.3/angularfire.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/libs/angularfire/0.8.2/angularfire.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/js/simple-login/1.6.2/firebase-simple-login.js"></script>

Comment: Thanks, but could you use the "edit" link (under the question's tags) to add the versions to your question. It's important information and should go into the question itself. Could you also include the version of Firebase that you are using? And why do you appear to have two different versions of AngularFire?

Comment: You are using a *very* old version of AngularFire. If you upgrade to the latest version the warning will disappear.